# Block textbox from numbers only VBA

Tags: vba

I want to restrict a textbox from numbers only, this means that I want any 'letters' and special characters except numbers

This is what I actually have:
Note: ...this snippet only works for letters, I can't even use punctuation marks

```
Private Sub TxtActividade_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
   Select Case KeyAscii
      Case 32, 65 To 90, 97 To 122 ''122
      Case Else
         KeyAscii = 0
         MsgBox "Only letters and special characteres", vbInformation, "Validation"
   End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude numbers from being entered, then do this:

```
Private Sub TxtActividade_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
   Select Case KeyAscii
      Case 48 To 57
         KeyAscii = 0
         MsgBox "Only letters and special characteres", vbInformation, "Validation"
   End Select
End Sub
```

KeyAscii values between 48 and 57 are numbers, and KeyAscii = 0 is effectively saying to cancel the keystroke.